# How can I create a sub folder in php

Tags: php

Hello I have created a script that allows an admin to create folders, but I need to be able to add a sub folder within each folder depending on which company id is selected, everything works apart from the creation of the sub-folder any help would be appreciated, as I still very new to PHP.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

$name is the main folder name which the admin makes by filling in a basic form.

$companyid is my sub folder variable which doesn't work, I've even changed it to $companyid = "hello"; to see if that would create a subfilder called 100 but it didn't.

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM folders WHERE name='".$name."' AND parentID='".$parentID."'" ;
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error selecting folder from database for comparison");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $msg = "Folder already exists in database. Try another one.";
    } else { 

        if(!empty($name)){      

            if(!empty($parentID) && $parentID!=0){
                $qq="SELECT name, company_id FROM folders WHERE parentID='".$parentID."'";
                $ress=mysql_query($qq);
                $rrr=mysql_fetch_assoc($ress);
                $mainFolderName = $rrr["name"];
                $companyid = $rrr["company_id"];

                //also create mkdir folder in script base, and make it writable
                $thisdir = getcwd();
                @mkdir($thisdir."/".'uploads'."/".$name."/".$companyid , 0777);
                //chmod($script_dir.$name, 777);
            } else { 

                //also create mkdir folder in script base, and make it writable
                $thisdir = getcwd();
                @mkdir($thisdir."/".'uploads'."/".$name."/".$companyid , 0777);
                //chmod($script_dir.$name, 777);

            }
```

**strong text**

Comment: What do you get when you remove the `@` sign before `mkdir`?

Comment: I get the same result the main folder is created but the sub-folder isn't

Comment: Try `, 0777, true);` and possibly `while($companyid = $rrr["company_id"]){...}`

Comment: Nope still the same result, its really bugging me now. but thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try the `while` loop? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Sorry to be thick but where shall I put the while loop?

Comment: Replace `$companyid = $rrr["company_id"];` with `while($companyid = $rrr["company_id"])` and bracing it `{...}` since you're fetching from DB.

Comment: Nope no errors, but still no sub folder, not to worry, but thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found my solution, it may be wrong but it works for me.

In my selection for the company which is also where the company id is registered I used $_POST so now my code looks like this:

```
    if(!empty($name)){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM folders WHERE name='".$name."' AND parentID='".$parentID."'" ;
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("oopsy, error selecting folder from database for comparison");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $msg = "Folder already exists in database. Try another one.";
    } else { 

        if(!empty($name)){      

            if(!empty($parentID) && $parentID!=0){
                $qq="SELECT name, company_id FROM folders WHERE parentID='".$parentID."'";
                $ress=mysql_query($qq);
                $rrr=mysql_fetch_assoc($ress);
                $mainFolderName = $rrr["name"];

                //also create mkdir folder in script base, and make it writable
                $thisdir = getcwd();
                mkdir($thisdir."/".'uploads'."/".$name."/".$_POST['company_id'] , 0777, true);
                //chmod($script_dir.$name, 777);
            } else { 

                //also create mkdir folder in script base, and make it writable
                $thisdir = getcwd();
                mkdir($thisdir."/".'uploads'."/".$name."/".$_POST['company_id'] , 0777, true);
                //chmod($script_dir.$name, 777);

            }
```

Thank you for all those who looked and thanks to  lxg and  Fred -ii for helping.